# Get rid of white tile borders in PhotoScroller

Tags: ios, catiledlayer

Apple has an iOS sample app called PhotoScroller, which demonstrates `CATiledLayer` and `UIScrollViewer`. The sample app shows white boxes around each tile, as a way of illustrating the tiling (i.e. when you zoom in, the tiles represent smaller parts of the image).

How can I get rid of these white lines? I've gone over the code and can't figure out where they've come from. (I'm new to iOS and Objective-C so maybe this is obvious.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`TilingView.m`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Listings/Classes_TilingView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Classes_TilingView_m-DontLinkElementID_10),

```
if (self.annotates) {
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0 / scale);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, tileRect);
}
```

This is the part which `strokes` the border of the tiles. Remove this part to get rid of the white tile borders.